# How to restore the navigation stack after page suspend / resume in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm just getting used to Xamarin.Forms and cant seem to find a standard way of restoring the navigation stack after a suspend / restore (like when the device gets rotated).

I'm using MVVM with the Xamarin.Forms.Labs stuff, so I can get an IXFormsApp, and get triggers for Resumed etc, but I dont understand how I'm meant to restore the navigation stack in my app?

For example, if I have my HomeView and HomeViewModel, which has a list view of items. Somebody clicks the list view item and it navigates to my ItemView and ItemViewModel. Then the user rotates the screen - how do I restore them to where they just were?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the current answer to this as of Xamarin.Forms 1.2 (and probably 1.3) is to add the following changes to your android activity.

Where your MainActivity would have looked like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "SomeName", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light")]
public class MainActivity : XFormsApplicationDroid
{
...
}
```

You need to tell Android not to destroy and restore your activity during screen sizes or orientation changes:

```
[Activity(Label = "SomeName", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : XFormsApplicationDroid
{
...
}
```

Xamarin.Forms will handle some degree of orientation changes in its own layouts.